# SharePoint : best way to insert a list item with formated hyperlink?

Tags: sharepoint

I have the following code:

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; 
SPList list = web.Lists[this.ListName];
SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
item["linktoAttachment"] = this.SiteAddress +  file.Url;
```

My question is how can I have friendly link text...

like in a classic hyperlink you have

```
<a href="technical link">friendly link here</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOur LinkToAttachment field Should of Type Url, then you can use the following:

```
item["linktoAttachment"] = string.Format("{0},{1}", this.SiteAddress +  file.Url, "friendly link here");
```

Another option is:

```
SPListItem newLink = list.Items.Add();
SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue();
value.Description = "friendly link here";
value.Url = this.SiteAddress +  file.Url;
newLink["linktoAttachment"] = value;
```